# Is there a postgres equivalent for python's int function?

Tags: postgresql

I need the following behaviour in postgres. Following is done in python console.

```
>>> int(-1.2)
-1
>>> int(1.2)
1
>>> int(0.2)
0
```

I would be okay with using the floor function of postgres, but I am not guaranteed to have only positive values.

```
template1=# select floor(-1.2), floor(1.2), floor(0.2);
 floor | floor | floor
-------+-------+-------
    -2 |     1 |     0
```

I can not use the ceil either for the same reason.

```
template1=# select ceil(-1.2), ceil(1.2), ceil(0.2);
 ceil | ceil | ceil
------+------+------
   -1 |    2 |    1
```

I can do something like crazy like this of course:

```
template1=# select cast(split_part(cast(1.2 as text), '.', 1) as integer), cast(split_part(cast(-1.2 as text), '.', 1) as integer), cast(split_part(cast(0.2 as text), '.', 1) as integer), cast(split_part(cast(-0.2 as text), '.', 1) as integer), cast(split_part(cast(1 as text), '.', 1) as integer);

 split_part | split_part | split_part | split_part | split_part
------------+------------+------------+------------+------------
          1 |         -1 |          0 |          0 |          1
```

But is there a simpler way than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `trunc()`.

```
select trunc(-1.2), trunc(1.2), trunc(0.2);

 trunc | trunc | trunc 
-------+-------+-------
    -1 |     1 |     0
(1 row)
```

Comment: Feel stupid for not making it that far into documentation. Thnx